# Integral roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics, integers

Actually we were told by our teacher that the quadratic equation that satisfies the conditions mentioned below has integral roots...

> Consider the equation- $ax^2+bx+c=0$ in its lowest form.
>
> 1. $a,b,c$ are integers
> 2. $a = 1$ or $-1$
> 3. $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square

But to my surprise while solving some high school level questions i came across the equation $2x²-5x-3=0$ which has two root, $3$ and $-1/2$ out of which the first root is integral for sure..which should not be so looking at the conditions.

Now my question is:
Where did my teacher or I went wrong?

If this is not the correct way to predict integral root for a quadratic equation then what is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any methods to solve for integer solution of a quadratic equation like $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048220/is-there-any-methods-to-solve-for-integer-solution-of-a-quadratic-equation-like)

Comment: Your equation has $a=2$, while the conditions given by your teacher require $a=1$ or $-1$

Comment: @Fotis That's the point n....i have a = 2 which must correspond to non integral roots but 3 is an integer. Ryt?

Comment: @Utkarsh It is definitely related to my question, provided of some facts that I gathered from answers and comments on the same. But the contradiction that we are left with is the main topic for this question.

Comment: @Darshitff The statement your teacher gave you says: "If conditions hold, then you have two integer roots". Now if you reverse that statement, it would read like "If you don't have two integers roots (so either one, or none) then at least one of the conditions doesn't hold. So in your example even though you found one integer root, the other wasn't, and indeed, not all of your conditions were satisfied. So in conclusion, the statement you have tells you when you have exactly two integers roots, rather than integer roots (i.e. one integer root) in general

Comment: Okay okay so there's the catch...

Comment: Now what to do of the question? Shall i delete it?

Comment: No, you should not delete the question. If @Fotis's comment answers your question, maybe you can ask them to post it as an answer. Or post an answer yourself.

Comment: @Fotis If you wish you may take the step!

Answer (score 1):

The statement your teacher gave you says: "If conditions hold, then you have two integer roots".
Now if you reverse that statement, it would read like "If you don't have two integers roots (so either one, or none) then at least one of the conditions doesn't hold.

So in your example even though you found one integer root, the other wasn't, which means that at least one of the three conditions was not satisfied, in particular you had $a=2$ instead of $a=±1$ as required.

In conclusion, the statement you have tells you when you have exactly two integers roots, rather than integer roots (i.e. one integer root) in general